# Applying equation to a Numpy array while preserving TIFF metadata (coordinates)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, metadata, numpy, rasterio

I wish to load a .tif image into a numpy array, apply a formula and then spit the image back out with the same geo/nodata metadata information.

So far I have created this, which does the processing but loses all metadata in the process and also applies the formula to nodata values:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('ndvi.tif') #import image array
ndviArray = np.array(img) #convert to numpy array

def ndvi2bio(x): #function to convert from ndvi to BIO
    return 400*(x)+680

vfunc = np.vectorize(ndvi2bio) #creating function function array...?

bioArray = vfunc(ndviArray) #applying the bio array to the formula array to give results.


#turn back into image...
bioImg = Image.fromarray(bioArray)

bioImg.save('BIOout.tif')
```

I've been reading into rasterio, I think I can replace the PIL image module with rasterio which will be more appropriate in this situation and allow me to keep my metadata from the TIFF.

How can I achieve this? So far I am struggling to find a tutorial which does this, it seems most others use several other modules. Can it be done with just rasterio and numpy? (img(+meta) -> numpy array -> img(+meta from original data))

Comment: You don't need to vectorise your `ndvi2bio` function.  Numpy will run the calculation over the entire array already. You are just slowing your calculation down by a massive amount (in a quick `timeit` test on a 100x100 array, calling the function 1000 times took 0.008 sec, while the vectorised function took 2 sec)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly easy.  You open and read the input raster as a numpy array, run your calculation, open the output raster in 'w' [write mode](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/writing.html) and use the georeferencing and other metadata (aka the [profile](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/profiles.html)) from the input raster.

```
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np


def ndvi2bio(x): #function to convert from ndvi to BIO
    return 400*(x)+680

with rio.open('ndvi.tif') as src:  # open raster dataset
    ndvi = src.read()  # read as numpy array
    profile = src.profile

bio = ndvi2bio(ndvi) #applying the bio array to the formula array to give results.

with rio.open('BIOout.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:  # open raster dataset in 'w' write mode using the
    dst.write(bio)                                   # georeferencing and other metadata from ndvi.tif
```

More introductory `rasterio` examples are in the [quickstart section of the docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I was confusing myself with the more complicated tutorials I was trying to follow elsewhere, I'll remember to go to the docs next time instead of google.